# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function is not in $L^1$.

Tags: operator-theory, harmonic-analysis

It is from my text book.

We know that the statement:

**if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $Mf\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$**

is not true.

In fact, if $Mf\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $f=0$. We can show this. If $a>0$ is arbitrary and $|x|>a$, then $$Mf(x)\geq^{step1} \frac{1}{\lambda (B(x,2|x|))}\int_{B(x,2|x|)}{|f(y)|dy} \geq^{step2} \frac{1}{\lambda (B(0,2|x|))}\int_{B(0,a)}{|f(y)|dy} =^{step3}\frac{const}{|x|^n}\int_{B(0,a)}{|f(y)|dy}. $$ Since $|x|^{n}$ is not integrable for $|x|>a$, it follows that $$  \int_{B(0,a)}{|f(y)|dy}=0.  $$

Question 1 (about step 2): I understand the first step. But I dont understand why and for what do we shift the center of our ball to $0$. Also I dont understand how we get this inequality.

Question 2: The same misunderstandings with the step 3. I even dont understands how we get $\frac{const}{|x|^n}$ after the third step.

Please help me to understand. If you just show the direction it will be very helpfull.

Comment: Q1 & Q2: $\lambda(B(x;2|x|))=\lambda(B(0;2|x|))=2^n|x|^n\lambda(B(0;1))$. The constant is $2^m\lambda(B(0;1))$. This follows by translation invariance and by the dilation property of Lebesgue measure $\lambda(rA)=r^n\lambda(A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 2 uses two facts: One is $B(0,a) \subseteq B(x,2|X|)$. [$|y|<a$ implies $|y-x|\leq |y|+a<2|x|$ since $|x| >a$]. Next, Lebesgue measure is translation invariant so the measure of any ball $B(u,R)$ is same as the measure of $B(0,R)$.

Step 3 has a typo.  Equality should be changed to $\geq$. The constant is just $a^{n}$. They are using  the fact that  $\frac {a^{n}} {|x|^{n}} <1$.

Comment: I understand this now. Thanks. How do you get that $const =a^n$? Also why do we bother about that $|x|^{-n}>a$? Why it is matter? It is the dominator in the fraction. Why do we bother about the integrability of this dominator if  we need not to integrate it?

Comment: And because we get that this integral is infinite we conclude that $Mf$ is not in $L^1$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But it's not true that $Mf(x)\ge c>0$ for $|x|>a$. (Clearly not, for example if $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ then $Mf\in L^2$...)